# How to skip column when persisting in Doctrine2?

Tags: mysql, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm, persistence

I have one column for the time when object is `created` and one for when it is `updated`.
When I create and persist new object I get the error from MySQL:

> updated cannot be null.

I didn't set any value to it because I want `updated` column to remain untouched and eventually get default database value whatever it is.

How to do tell doctrine to persist only those columns which values I explicitly set/changed?

Comment: Show us your entity config - you must have set it to require a value

Comment: Still waiting for an answer at http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2045

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your column definition has `nullable` defined as `true`.

```
/**
 * @Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $updated;
```

Comment: doesn't work. and if you look at source code you'll see that `nullable` used only for relations/joins

Comment: @coviex erm, nope... http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-column

Answer (score 0):

Then you should set your column in your entity to nullable false.

In your Entity:

```
/**
 * @var datetime $date_updated
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $date_updated;
```

Comment: If it was set to `nullable=false` that would mean it requires a value

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I have changed it.